# custom android nougat date and time picker

Tags: android, android-layout-weight, android-7.0-nougat

I am customizing date & time picker. 
When I try it on android Nougat, the OK and Cancel buttons seems in semi-transparent gray. see attached image.
in android 6 - it looks just fine... 
Any ideas? 
Thanks

```
<style name="AppTheme.Dialog" parent="AppTheme.Dialog.Base">
    <item name="android:datePickerDialogTheme">@style/MyDatePickerDialogTheme</item>
    <item name="android:timePickerDialogTheme">@style/MyTimePickerDialogTheme</item>
</style>

<style name="MyDatePickerDialogTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="android:colorAccent">#00FF00</item>
</style>

<style name="MyTimePickerDialogTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="android:colorAccent">#00FF00</item>
</style>
```

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

OK, I got it: I added to MyDatePickerDialogTheme & MyTimePickerDialogTheme the item:

```
<item name="buttonStyle">@style/MyPickerButtonStyle</item>
```

And then:

```
<style name="MyPickerButtonStyle" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Button">
    <item name="android:textColor">#00c8f8</item>
</style>
```

It fixed the problem.

It happened because I defined my own buttonStyle ...